# Unable to install PHP on FreeBSD 9.3

Tags: php, installation, freebsd

I tried to install Php5 on my FreeBSD server I just got, following a tutorial.

So first I did

```
cd /usr/ports/lang/php5
```

then

```
make config
```

didn't change any option there, finally I did

```
 make install
```

but it gave me a few errors.

```
root@ns******:/usr/ports/lang/php5 # make install
===>   php5-5.4.39 depends on file: /usr/local/bin/autoconf-2.69 - not found
===>    Verifying install for /usr/local/bin/autoconf-2.69 in /usr/ports/devel/autoconf
===>   autoconf-2.69 depends on executable: gm4 - found
===>   autoconf-2.69 depends on executable: help2man - not found
===>    Verifying install for help2man in /usr/ports/misc/help2man
===>   help2man-1.43.3_1 depends on package: p5-Locale-gettext>=0 - not found
===>    Verifying install for p5-Locale-gettext>=0 in /usr/ports/devel/p5-Locale-gettext
===>  Installing for p5-Locale-gettext-1.05_4
===>   p5-Locale-gettext-1.05_4 depends on file: /usr/local/bin/perl5.16.3 - found
===>   p5-Locale-gettext-1.05_4 depends on shared library: libintl.so - found (/usr/local/lib/libintl.so)
===>  Checking if p5-Locale-gettext already installed
===>   Registering installation for p5-Locale-gettext-1.05_4 as automatic
pkg-static: lstat(/usr/ports/devel/p5-Locale-gettext/work/stage/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/mach/5.16/auto/Locale/gettext/gettext.so): No such file or directory
pkg-static: lstat(/usr/ports/devel/p5-Locale-gettext/work/stage/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/mach/5.16/Locale/gettext.pm): No such file or directory
pkg-static: lstat(/usr/ports/devel/p5-Locale-gettext/work/stage/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/man/man3/Locale::gettext.3.gz): No such file or directory
*** [fake-pkg] Error code 74

Stop in /usr/ports/devel/p5-Locale-gettext.
*** [build-depends] Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/misc/help2man.
*** [install] Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/misc/help2man.
*** [build-depends] Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/devel/autoconf.
*** [build-depends] Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/lang/php5.
*** [install] Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/lang/php5.
```

So, I downloaded autoconf-2.69 from the gnu site then it couldn't find libtool22. Downloaded it aswell, 'fixed' it.
But then another error.

I am not on my pc so I can't post the error here, but to resume, it gives me permission denied to use autoconf and chmod isn't working (the command my friend told me to use at least)!

I uploaded the things via bitvise ssh if it helps.
It's a dedicated server, I have root access, got it on kimsufi.

How can I fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gettext` port has been splitted into two different ports so you have outdates software that should be updated prior to the installations.

First, update your ports tree:

```
portsnap fetch update
```

This may take a while.

Then you have to install handful tool `portmaster`:

```
make -C /usr/ports/ports-mgmt/portmaster install clean
```

Then you have to check whether your ports are in consistent state:

```
portmaster --check-depends 
portmaster --check-port-dbdir 
portmaster -y --clean-distfiles
```

Then you have to deinstall old `gettext`:

```
pkg delete -f gettext
```

Now you probably want to install `www/mod_php5` before `lang/php5` - apache module is the separate port now, while CLI/FPM are still at the old location.

```
make -C /usr/ports/www/mod_php5 install clean
make -C /usr/ports/lang/php5 install clean
make -C /usr/ports/lang/php5-extensions install clean
```

Fresh `gettext` will be installed automatically as dependence, as well as lot of other fresh ports.

While your host is a bit outdated, you'll need to update all the ports due to the security reasons:

```
portmaster -atd
```

You can stuck with another dependency errors, so just deinstall corresponding port (like `gettext` was), and launch `portmaster -aRtd` again and again until all the problems will be resolved. If some strange messages still present, you can reinstall all the ports at once by `portmaster -aftd`

P.S.
You should install software from ports/packages ONLY to avoid unforseen consequencies.

Answer (score 0):

Will `pkg install p5-Locale-gettext` help you? (be careful if it offers removal and/or reinstallation of other packages)